# Как передать звук с ссылки

Tags: html, vue.js, radio

Подскажите , как сделать так , чтобы при клике на кнопку я слышал звук с онлайн радио ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         url: "https://pcradio.ru/radio/top-100-love",
      }
   },
   methods: {
      play() {
        this.audio.play();
      },
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <audio :src="url" controls></audio>
      <button @click="play()">Play</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: вам нужно получить url непосредственно аудио-файла, и его уже воспроизводить. полагаю на радио будет что-то вроде потока, тогда еще сложнее будет. :)